# Pass an object between Components with service

Tags: angular

I read in several pages that the best way to pass an object between components, when doing the routing, is the use of a service.

I have relied on this last example (http://plnkr.co/edit/NpLKAgY3FkzhOK9eBeIb?p=preview) and I made the following code that gives me problems:

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class tableService {

    public category: Category;
}
```

Component 1:

```
export class tableComponent {
    categorys: Category[] = []; 
    category: Category;

passItemCat(event: any) {
    this.category = {
        Code: "09",
        Attachments: [],
        Description: "eee",
        Response: {
            Destination: "",
            HtmlText: "",
            Text: "",
            Type: "",
        },
        Taxonomy: "ddd",
     }
    event.preventDefault(); 
}


constructor(public _tableService: tableService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    //get API for categorys
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._tableService.category = this.category;
}
}
```

Template Componente 1

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of categorys">
            <td>
                <nav>
                    <button routerLink="/ModifyCategory" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="passItemCat($event)">Modify</button>
                </nav>
            </td>
```

Componente 2

```
export class modifyCategoryComponent{
    category: Category;

    constructor(public _tableService: tableService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.category = this._tableService.category;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the OnInit of the component 2, which does not find elements in this._tableService.category.

PS. In this step (I proceed in small steps to learn) use a static category on click, subsequently I want to read the item of the component template 1. if you want to suggest some improvements are all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because `modifyCategoryComponent` reads `_tableservice.category` before `tableComponent` set `_tableService.category`.

If you instead use an `Observable` then the receiving component gets notified when a value is set or updated.

```
@Injectable()
export class tableService {
  private category:BehaviorSubject<Category> = new BehaviorSubject<Category>(null);
  get $category() {
    return this.category.asObservable();
  }
  setCategory(value:Category) {
    this.category.next(value);
  }
}
```

Set a new category

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this._tableService.setCategory(this.category);
}
```

Subscribe to category changes

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._tableService.$category.subscribe(value => this._tableService.category = value);
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but i can't buil ngOnInit if you can explain me how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What does "can't build ngOnInit` means. What is "it" in "explain me how it works"?

Comment: I mean that ngOnInit give me error and prevent build ts file. I refer to Subscribe to category changes, because: $category is not present in Component 2;

Comment: Build:Property '$category' does not exist on type 'modifyCategoryComponent'. Build:Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Sorry, there was a `_tableService.` missing.

Comment: ok, suppose that (value => this.category = value). unfortunately the category value remains null...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132104/discussion-between-ferox-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: What if you use `value => console.log('value', value)` instead? Does something get printed to the browser console?

Comment: Print twice: null

Comment: what do you get when you add `console.log('category', value` in `setCategory()` before `this.category.next(value)`?

Comment: The object... Can you explain how should work this:

get $category() {
        return this.category.asObservable();
    }

Comment: Not sure what to explain. It allows to access the subject as `Observable`. You can check the link in my answer for other examples.Sorry. Where do you provide `tableService`?

Comment: OK! the problem was the provide... there was a provide in appcomponet and in the first component. I removed the Provide from first component and passed it easily!!